# How to Partitioning a table using a LIKE criteria in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-like, database-partitioning

I've a large table to partition by value of a field of varchar(200) type. I have already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936384/partitioning-a-database-table-in-mysql) but because the size of the field I cannot use this solution.
My question is: Can I use a Like criteria as LIKE 'b%' or LIKE 'o%' and so on?
If not, How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Antonio

Comment: "but because the size of the field" --- uhm, even if you have varchar limited by 200 chars you can use that solution.

Comment: Sure, but I'm looking for something of more immediate. I can use this solution writing a script that for each partition do something like  
    partition p1 values less than ('bzzzz....')
199 times z.
Anyway, if I can't use a LIKE criteria I'll use that solution. :)

Comment: you don't need to write "z" 199 times. Just write `less than ('c')`

Comment: @zerkms: you beat me by a minute. @Antonio: `less than ('c')` is better than `'less than 'bzz...z'` as it's shorter and catches strings that have `'b{what|ever}'`, e.g. if it contains characters with bigger ascii order than `z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better specify the range as

```
less than ('c')
```

It is short and readable.

Comment: I get an error:
`ERROR 1064(42000): VALUES value must be of the same type as partition function near '), partition p2 values less than ('e'),...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that partitioning on varchar is allowed only if partitioning is by key (no duplicate values and no null values allowed).

[Here a discussion](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,239843,239843#msg-239843)

I tried to perform partitioning using a function that "converts" to integer values as ASCII(), but it doesn't compare in Mysql supported functions in partitioning expression.

[List of supported functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html)