# How to decide varchar partition RANGE in MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql, string, partitioning, varchar

**Backgroud**

I have a very big table, the table is just like this

```
CREATE TABLE tb_doc (
did mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
title varchar(80) NOT NULL default '',
...,
PRIMARY KEY  (did), 
KEY title (title)
) 
TYPE=MyISAM;
```

The type of title is varchar(80), most of the time title will be pure number strings like '111111','2222222','44444444', some times it will be utf-8 strings, like '3a','a4' or "中国" (Chinese characters).

I've already used HASH (did) to do partition, but my SELECT statements are alway like

```
SELECT did, title,... FROM tb_doc WHERE title= '1111111';
SELECT did, title,... FROM tb_doc WHERE title= '2222222';
```

So I want to use title to do partition, hope this would be faster. Now it comes the question.

**Experiment**

I used the following statement:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (title)(
PARTITION p00 VALUES LESS THAN (1),         # not pure number strings
PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (500000),    # pure number strings from 1 to 500k
PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (1000000),   # pure number strings from 500k to 1000k
PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN (1500000),   # pure number strings from 1000k to 1500k
..........                                  # ......    

PARTITION pn VALUES LESS THAN (25000000),   # the biggest number now
)
;
```

**Similar Questions**

I read the following two Q&As:
[Partitioning a database table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936384/partitioning-a-database-table-in-mysql)
[How to Partitioning a table using a LIKE criteria in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442449/how-to-partitioning-a-table-usign-a-like-criteria-in-mysql/)
but they are for English world, not work in my situation.

**Questions**

1. Use title to do partition is better, right?
2. Can you give me a "utf-8" RANGE example? 
   I tryied '500000','1000000',...,but they do not work.
3. If I use SELECT xxx from tb_doc WHERE title='12345', dose MySQL fetch data from partation 1 only?
4. This table is ~50GB, how many partitions are optimum?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

May I note that `VARCHAR` will have problems with storing characters from multiple languages properly, better use `NVARCHAR`.

HASH partitioning is used to distribute load over partitions evenly. I would say, that first you should partition by something meaningful to a human (columns appearing in Where clause often) and then do HASH sub-partitioning to utilise as many cores as possible at the same time. So number of HASH sub-partitiong in this case will <= No cores.

I would suggest you creating a clustered index on `title` column. This will speed up your queries.

And in relation to your questions:

1. Not neceserally. It will speed up queries, because of clustered index, not partitioning.
   Use partitioning to manage the table: eg. delete many rows quickly.
   If a good proportion of your queries looks for many rows (not just 1) or `title` is not a `UNIQUE` column, then you may consider Partition
2. As an example of UTF-8 partition boundary I would say: `less then ('c')`
3. Depending on how you define partitioning it may hit 1, several or all partitions.
4. There is no penalty for having many partitions, but a table in MySQL 5.5+ can have upto 1024 partitions and sub-partitions.

When you whan to do partitioning by string value, use `KEY PARTITIONING` as described here: [18.2.5. KEY Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-key.html).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tm1 (
    s1 CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY
)
PARTITION BY KEY(s1)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

Set number of partitions same as there are letters in your alphabet (or all alphabets you anticipate to see in the table) to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning by `title`, even if you could do it, will *not* speed up

```
SELECT did, title,... FROM tb_doc WHERE title= '1111111';
```

For a further discussion of the limitations of PARTITIONing, plus what few use cases it will help, see [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint);