# SQL - Split table based upon a column's content

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

I have a large database (~50,000 rows) with 20 columns, and I want to "split" the data based upon the values in the third column (called FEATURE_CLASS). The values of FEATURE_CLASS are all of type VARCHAR(), and I want to create however many tables I'd need to replace the single, large table with many smaller tables each entitled with whatever the original table's FEATURE_CLASS value was.

Not sure of the best way to go about this, I was thinking something along the lines of creating a temporary table which would serve as an index, each row carrying a unique value of FEATURE_CLASS, then to iterate over the temp table and perform copying operations for each row of the temp table. I'm not sure really where to go from here, any help/ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 50,000 rows is not really that large. Anyway, I'm not clear about the column data ... is it that the values in the 'feature_class' is a comma separated list, or some other situation?  Can you post a small example of the data in that column?

Comment: Read this! https://stackoverflow.com/a/16812941/3617531

Comment: I would agree with @PaulT. in that 50K rows is not large at all.  If you are having performance problems with that table size, you likely just need to optimize.  I could imagine you might have other reasons to do this as well.

Comment: Sorry to break it to you, but 50K rows is not "large". And you really shouldn't "split" the table into multiple mini-tables. If you do this you will multiply your query and maintenance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to create a result set of statements that will create the tables for you and populate with the correct data.  Run the below to generate the statements.  You can then execute these statements manually (copy/paste) or from within a script.

**SQL Server Example**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    'SELECT * INTO [' + TableName.FEATURE_CLASS + '] FROM TableName WHERE FEATURE_CLASS = ''' + TableName.FEATURE_CLASS + ''';'
FROM
    TableName
```

If you have any special characters in the FEATURE_CLASS column, you might want to consider removing them in the script above to prevent table names that are either invalid or tough to work with.

For example:

```
...
    'SELECT * INTO [' + REPLACE(TableName.FEATURE_CLASS, '.', '') + '] FROM TableName WHERE FEATURE_CLASS = ''' + TableName.FEATURE_CLASS + ''';'
...
```

**MySQL Example**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', DB1.FEATURE_CLASS, 
        '` AS SELECT * FROM DB1 WHERE FEATURE_CLASS = ''', 
        DB1.FEATURE_CLASS, ''';') AS statements
FROM DB1;
```

This will give you a MySQL command something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `feature_class_value` AS 
    SELECT * FROM DB1 
        WHERE FEATURE_CLASS = 'feature_class_value';
```

Check out the MySQL docs for more info on CREATE TABLE SELECT options https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to "generate the statements". I've tried to run your query (with TableName changed appropriately) and the query returns nothing (this is within the SQL tab phpMyAdmin by the way).

As far as scripting is concerned, would I be able to run an SQL command in phpMyAdmin that creates the tables based upon a SELECT DISTINCT within the FEATURE_CLASS column, then perhaps populate the tables in a following statement?

Comment: Can you provide the exact query you are trying?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT
  'SELECT * INTO [' + DB1.FEATURE_CLASS + '] FROM DB1 WHERE FEATURE_CLASS = ''' + DB1.FEATURE_CLASS + ''';'
 FROM
  DB1`

Comment: I've tried various other modified queries as well, including with backquotes on the table name (e.g. `DB1` instead of DB1).

Comment: I think the problem is you are using MySQL, not SQL Server.  I see you had it tagged for both and I ran with SQL Server.  I updated my answer to include a MySQL example.